# Use of %s,%f,... when plotting text with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently plotting with matplotlib (pylab actually), and would like to do the following:

1. Declare a variable, e.g. `a=2.`
2. Print some text on my graph: `plt.text(x,y,r'an equation involving "a"')`

What I have done to plot that equation is to write `plt.text(x,y,r'$2x+3.5$')` (this will use LaTeX). However instead of writing myself that 2, I'd like to write something like `plt.text(x,y,r'$%fx+3.5$',a)`. In this case, "a" is passed as an argument, and this won't work.

Also, what if `a` is of type: numpy.float64?

Is there anyway to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You can use regular python string formatting for this.  There are currently two conventions, and I still use the old one, which looks like this: `plt.text(x,y,r'$2%i+3.5$' % a)`.  See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add strings together.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ys = [x**2 + 3.5 for x in xrange(20)]
xs = range(20)
plt.plot(xs,ys)

a = '2'

plt.text(6, 50,r'$'+a+'x+3.5$')
plt.show()
```

If a isn't a string, you can make it one!  `str(a)`

or use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)